# Data structure for quick clique lookup

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is a good algorithm for finding a clique and getting all members of that clique? 
For example i have:

```
a-b-c-d
e-f-g
h-i
x-y-x
```

where each line represent a clique where all members know each other.
Now given a node (say `a`) i want to quickly find the clique `a-b-c-d` and get a list of the members `[a, b, c, d]`

I can always have a dictionary of node to list of nodes and have each member point to the list of the rest of the members:

```
a -> [b, c, d]
b -> [a, c, d]
c -> [a, b, d]
...
```

but i'd be duplicating a lot of data.

EDIT: updates are not frequent and should be assumed to be static. members only belong to one clique

Comment: What sorts of updates are possible? Do you need to support dynamic insertions or deletions? Are all elements part of exactly one clique?

Comment: `g` belongs to two cliques in your example.  Please clarify.

Comment: one way is to sort the elements in each clique. lookup now will be done each sorted list, so total complexity is assuming n lists and maximum m elements in a longest clique. o(n)*o(mlogm)

Comment: mmm im not trying to determine if there are cliques. i already know each node is in 1 clique only

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to have a hybrid hash table / linked list. Store each clique as a circularly, doubly-linked list of all the clique elements. Then, have a hash table mapping every element to the linked list cell that represents it. To list all the elements of a clique containing some element, look up the cell for that element and follow the circular list to list off the remaining elements of the clique.

This data structure also supports combining two cliques in time O(1) (look up any two elements of the cliques through the hash table and splice the circular lists together) and adding or removing an element from a clique in time O(1) by splicing them in or out of a circular list. You can list clique membership in O(k) time, where k is the number of elements in the clique, and the whole thing uses O(n) space.

Hope this helps!

Comment: shouldnt the space complexity be O(nk) where k is the number of elements in each linked list?

Comment: Every element belongs to exactly one linked list, so if you sum up the total number of linked list cells, you'll only have n of them. Overall, that gives just O(n) space usage.